# Callbacks in Dart: dart:ffi only supports calling static Dart functions from native code

Tags: flutter, dart, ffi

This post is a duplicate of the Github Issue [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/47405).

`dart --version`
Dart SDK version: 2.15.0-116.0.dev (dev) (Thu Sep 16 09:47:01 2021 -0700) on "linux_x64"

I've been looking up [examples](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/samples/ffi/sample_ffi_functions_callbacks.dart) for callbacks and I have tried to get callbacks working for me in FFI.

#### My current situation

I have a function in my library which expects a pointer to a function. The bindings for the same generated by `ffigen` seem correct to me.

```
int SetCallback(
    CallbackType callback,
  ) {
    return _SetCallback(
      callback,
    );
  }

  late final _SetCallbackPtr =
      _lookup<NativeFunction<Int32 Function(CallbackType)>>(
          'SetCallback');
  late final _SetCallback =
      _SetCallbackPtr.asFunction<int Function(CallbackType)>();
```

where, `typedef CallbackType = Pointer<NativeFunction<Void Function(Uint32)>>;`.

What I want to do here is to setup this callback in Dart, pass it to the FFI, essentially using it as my callback as I would have in C. In my API which abstracts away from FFI code (which means I have a class MyLibrary full of static functions that the user will call directly, which in turn calls functions from an object _nativeLibrary of the class MyNativeLibrary I have created), I have:

```
  static int SetCallback({required CallbackFuncDart callback}) {
    Pointer<NativeFunction<CallbackFunc>> pointer = Pointer.fromFunction(callback);

    int status = _nativeLibrary.SetCallback(
      pointer,
    );
    if (STATUS_OK != status) {
      throw LibLexemeException(status);
    }
    return status;
  }

typedef CallbackFunc = Void Function(Uint32);
typedef CallbackFuncDart = void Function(int);
```

While [the sqlite ffi example](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/samples/ffi/sqlite/docs/sqlite-tutorial.md) states here that

> Features which dart:ffi does not support yet:
>
> ```
> Callbacks from C back into Dart.
> ```

I believe the docs haven't been updated to reflect the changes at [the samples here.](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/tree/master/samples/ffi) The samples haven't been very clear due to them not having any C/C++ files, or an idea of how the C functions work. Even so, I think [this example](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/samples/ffi/sample_ffi_functions_callbacks.dart) contains a segment(last code block) where a Dart function is being passed as a callback which I have replicated in my program. It is not clear to me how this will work but upon trying to compile my program I get:

```
ERROR: ../lib/library_lexeme.dart:180:74: Error: fromFunction expects a static function as parameter. dart:ffi only supports calling static Dart functions from native code. Closures and tear-offs are not supported because they can capture context.
ERROR:     Pointer<NativeFunction<CallbackFunc>> pointer = Pointer.fromFunction(callback);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Dart 3.2, you now have the ability to create callbacks from any Dart function or closure, expanding beyond static or top-level functions.

There are currently two ways to achieve this:

- **[NativeCallable.isolateLocal:](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.0/dart-ffi/NativeCallable/NativeCallable.isolateLocal.html)** This constructs a `NativeCallable` that must be invoked from the *same* thread that created it. It builds upon the functionality provided by [Pointer.fromFunction](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.0/dart-ffi/Pointer/fromFunction.html), which is limited to creating function pointers from static or top-level functions.
- **[NativeCallable.listener:](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.0/dart-ffi/NativeCallable/NativeCallable.listener.html)** This constructs a `NativeCallable` that can be invoked from *any* thread. This functionality was introduced in Dart 3.1 and only supports `void` functions.

Here's a revised version of your example, now incorporating the `NativeCallable.isolateLocal`:

```dart
static int SetCallback({required CallbackFuncDart callback}) {
  final nativeCallable = NativeCallable<CallbackFunc>.isolateLocal(callback);
  int status = _nativeLibrary.SetCallback(nativeCallable.nativeFunction);
  if (STATUS_OK != status) throw LibLexemeException(status);
  return status;
}

typedef CallbackFunc = Void Function(Uint32);
typedef CallbackFuncDart = void Function(int);
```

Answer (score 0):

The short version is that you can't pass your callnback as an argument:

```dart
static int SetCallback({required CallbackFuncDart callback}) {
    Pointer<NativeFunction<CallbackFunc>> pointer = Pointer.fromFunction(callback); // <-- this isn't considered a static function
```

It's quite annoying but you must use a static function defined ahead of time for your dart callbacks to be called from C.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently for now only static functions can be passed via ffi. But if you have to access an instance's data and you're sure that the instance exists you can use my workaround. I use a static list to the instances. This is stupid and ugly but it works for me:

```
class CallbackClass {
  static Int8 classCallback(int id) { 
    final instance = instanceList[id];
    return instance.instanceCallback();
  }

  Int8 instanceCallback() { return instanceId; }

  static List<CallbackClass> instanceList = <CallbackClass>[];
  late final int instanceId;

  CallbackClass {
    instanceId = instanceList.length;
    instanceList.insert(instanceId, this);
    myFFImapping.passCallback(instanceId, Pointer.fromFunction<>(classCallback);)
  }
}
```

I omitted the necessary c code, FFI mapping and casting to correct types for clarity, so it obviously won't compile like this.